# Flask-SQLAlchemy achieve 1 to many relationship that backfills parent when child is updated

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

Currently I have two tables Plan (plans) and User (users) and there is a foreign key constraint on users which references plans.id

When I create a new user I want to assign a plan to that user via plan.id

Here is how I am currently accomplishing this but I do feel there must be a better approach as it feels very manual and there is no real relation between the two via the ORM.

```
class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    firstname = db.Column(db.String(30), nullable=False)
    lastname = db.Column(db.String(30), nullable=False)
    plan_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('plans.id'))

class Plan(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'plans'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False, default='free')
    user = db.relationship('User', backref='plan', lazy=True, uselist=False)
    created_at = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)


plan = Plan(title='free')
db.session.add(plan)
db.session.commit()
user = User(
    firstname=firstname,
    lastname=lastname,
    plan_id=plan.id,
)
db.session.add(user)
db.session.commit()
```

As you can see I am creating a plan then committing it and then I am grabbing the id of that plan and passing it to the User Model and assigning it to plan_id

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Please [edit] your question so that the title describes the *purpose* of the code, rather than its *mechanism*.  We really need to understand the motivational context to give good reviews.  Thanks!

Comment: Thank you - all done.

Answer (score 1):

I see one immediate improvement: take advantage of the **session** mechanism to enforce data consistency.

Since you are adding two records that are related, if the operation fails in the middle, you should **roll back** changes completely, so that you don't end up with orphaned records.

Make it an **atomic** (all or nothing) operation.

All you have to do is start a session, then commit at the end, or rollback if an an exception occurred.

Thus you could have a block like this:

```
session = Session()
try:
    db.session.add(some_object)
    db.session.add(some_other_object)
    db.session.commit()
except:
    # log exception here
    db.session.rollback()
```

Or better yet, use a context manager for the session object eg:

```
Session = sessionmaker(engine)

with Session.begin() as session:
    session.add(some_object)
    session.add(some_other_object)
```

Have a [look](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session) at the docs for more details.